# Do the x86-64 compilers optimize to use smaller registers (eax instead of rax)?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64, compiler-optimization

I am just starting to learn assembly, so apologies if this is a dumb question, but I was playing around with some code compiled from cpp to assembly just to see what the instructions look like. And noticed something strange:

.cpp:

```
int main() {
    long a = 8;
    long b = 9;
    return a*b;
}
```

.s:

```
1 main:
2    push    rbp
3    mov     rbp, rsp
4    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 8     
5    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 9     
6    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]  ; 8-bytes (#8) areloaded into an 8-byte registers
7    mov     edx, eax                ; ONLY FIRST 4 bytes (#8) are moved into 4-byte reg
8    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16] ; 8-bytes (#9) areloaded into an 8-byte registers
9    imul    eax, edx                ; ONLY FIRST 4 bytes (#9) are used in mult
10   pop     rbp
11   ret
```

what caught my attention is that after being loaded into an 8 byte register (rax), when they are subsequently used, either moved, or multiplied as a result, only the first 4 bytes are used. So for example when the value 8 is moved  on line 7, the 32 bit version of rax, eax, is accessed? Similarly in line 9, only the first 32 bits of the 8-byte representation of 9 is used.

Am I correct in believing that this is some sort of optimization?

If it is, what is the reason for doing so?

Comment: Although my compiler was quite a bit different, when I switched the return type of the function to long; it used the registers a bit more as expected.   You might choose a different function than main because standards wankers.

Comment: interesting. It did not occur to me that the function return type might have something to do with it

Comment: This code is clearly not optimized (compiled with optimization enabled/as a release build) - had it been, the code would likely be more like ‘mov eax, 72; ret’.

Comment: from the compilers perspective, your function amounts to `return (int)((long)8 * (long)9); `   The sub-opts aren't so obvious in modern compilers, but if you look at 16 bit ones, they took pretty aggressive action on this, because `long*long` was way worse than `int*int`.

Comment: What compiler is this?  MSVC where `long` is a 32-bit type, or gcc/clang targeting non-Windows where it's a 64-bit type?

Comment: Also note that you've clearly compiling with optimization *disabled* (otherwise constant-propagation would just result in `mov eax, 8*9` / `ret`).  Oh, this must be targeting the x86-64 System V ABI (Linux or MacOS) because it's keeping locals in the red-zone, below RSP.  So `long` is 8 bytes.  Looks like GCC, given the reloading into RAX and then moving from there. Yeah it, seems @mevets is right, GCC is optimizing based on the implicit conversion of the result to only use a 32-bit `imul`.  This saves code-size, and is faster on some older x86-64 CPUs, especially low-power Silvermont.